# How to display dataframe table in telegram bot using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bots, telegram

I am doing stock market price bot project using python.
So I want to display the top gainers and top losers list after user clicks the button top gainers or losers.
So I am using pandas dataframe for display the tables using **scraping** the gainers url.In pycharm and jupyter notebook it is printing the tables.
But after I tried to print it on telegram bot using

```
import telegram
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.moneycontrol.com/markets/global-indices/'
response = requests.get(url)
print(response)
market = pd.read_html(url)
new_market = market[0]
new_market2 = new_market[['Name','Current Value','%Change']]
update.message.reply_text(new_market2.to_markdown())
```

it is not giving me in dataframe table format. How to display this new_market dataframe on telegram bot in proper format.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found a great tool for that need, it is called tabulate.

It prints tabular data and works with DataFrame.

```
from tabulate import tabulate
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_two' : [0.0001, 1e-005 , 1e-006, 1e-007],
                   'column_3' : ['ABCD', 'ABCD', 'long string', 'ABCD']})

print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))

+----+-----------+-------------+
|    |   col_two | column_3    |
|----+-----------+-------------|
|  0 |    0.0001 | ABCD        |
|  1 |    1e-05  | ABCD        |
|  2 |    1e-06  | long string |
|  3 |    1e-07  | ABCD        |

 bot.send_message(chat_ids, f'<pre>{table}</pre>', parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
```